# Setting up wireless access point?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I recently moved and the router and modem our on the first floor.

However, there is no way for me to run cable upstairs where my PC and everything are. I have wireless access but rather than purchase a wireless adapter for my PC, I would like to figure out a way to set up a router upstairs that picks up the downstairs signal so I could use cables upstairs to route the connection to my PC and my gaming system.

I figured the way would be to set up a router as an access point using the same ESSID and password as the main router, but all of the set-up guides I've read state that for this to work a cable must be connected directly from the second router to the original router in order for this to work.

Anything I could do? No way to connect to the primary router's wireless network with the second one and have it broadcast the same ESSID so I could have a wireless router upstairs as well?

Comment: What Access points do you have?  Most consumer grade don't do this (easily)

Answer (score 0):

configure your second router as a **repeater** and connect your PC to it with a cable.
same setup works for me.

Comment: A repeater would work if there laptop had a wireless card, but the signal was too weak to reach it. What is being described in the question wouldn't benefit from a repeater.

Comment: if the second router bridges the signal to the ethernet ports it would exactly do what he want, and all "home routers" I know do that (even my 8 year old avm router). It's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

The setup you are describing is a wireless bridge

router -> wireless --> wireless -> wired -> Laptop without a wireless card

I assume from your description that you have 2 wireless routers, and a laptop that doesn't have wireless capability.

The second router (the one closest to your laptop) will need to support bridged mode. Very few consumer devices support this out of the box. Luckily you can hack the firmware on your router to enable advanced features such as bridging. Checkout the [dd-wrt project](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index).

If your second router is on the supported list, you can then flash it with new firmware, and then follow [these instructions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge).

Be aware that flashing a router is not a simple task, and there is a real chance of bricking your router.

At the end of the day, it may be easier to just go buy a wireless adapter for your laptop. You can find them for $20 on newegg.com

Answer (score 0):

What about a device to run the [LAN over the powerline](https://www.google.com/search?q=lan%20over%20power#q=lan%20over%20power&source=univ&tbm=shop).  I've used this in my own house when I found a cheap one on Amazon and was able to get the LAN extended where my wireless didn't reach.